# Alternate content for flash | Magento

Tags: flash, alt, alternate

Ok so I have my home page which uses flash here:

http://www.emmaphillipsbridal.com/

If I try and add some alt code so that ipad and iphone users can see something instead of a blank page, but when i save the code it disapears, i have seen a few people have mentioned this issue but i can not find a solution.

The code for the flash is:

```
<div class="flash">
<object width="980" height="665" data="http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/header_v8.swf?xmlUrl=http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/xml_folder/" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<param name="data" value="http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/header_v8.swf?xmlUrl=http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/xml_folder/" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
<param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
<param name="src" value="http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/header_v8.swf?xmlUrl=http://www.dansiop.com/epbs/skin/frontend/base/theme137/flash/xml_folder/" />
</object>
</div>
```

The design xml on that page is:

```
<!--<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
<block type="reports/product_viewed" name="home.reports.product.viewed" alias="product_viewed" template="reports/home_product_viewed.phtml" after="product_new"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
<block type="reports/product_compared" name="home.reports.product.compared" template="reports/home_product_compared.phtml" after="product_viewed"><action method="addPriceBlockType"><type>bundle</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template></action></block>
</reference><reference name="right">
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.viewed</alias></action>
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>right.reports.product.compared</alias></action>
</reference>-->
```

Can anyone give me some ideas on how i can display something else for users who do not have flash?

Thanks in advance.

DanSiop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed any swf object in a web page.

This JS library will allow you to achieve just that and is considered as being an Adobe best practice.

It comes with a handy generator which will allow you to create a html page with the correct javascript/html as well.

Also check these out:

- [SWF object - why should I use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213930/swf-object-why-should-i-use-it)
- [.swf positionning is not contained on page, in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8571999/swf-positionning-is-not-contained-on-page-in-chrome)

Comment: thank you my man! for some reason though i can get it to work perfectly but when i go back to the magento admin the code for the alternate content has gone! do not understand, i have to keep a backup of the code to paste in every time - very odd indeed.